# Excel connection error in SSIS

Tags: c#, .net, excel, ssis

I am counting the number of excel sheets in a workbook by using GetSchema.("Tables") in a SSIS script task.
The code is giving the error :

> The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file
>   ''. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need
>   permission to view and write its data.

When a blank workbook is opened and the code is run, the target excel sheet is opening in read-only mode.
However if excel is not opened, the code is not working.

I have tried

- Delay validation property
- con.dispose()
- File not in read-only mode, all permissions look good.

I have a number of other files, which run just fine. But only one has this error.

How to get rid of this error?

Comment: This may be a bit of an obvious question, but have you ensured that you have the correct write permissions on the folder which the excel file is in? Are the other files which run fine in the same directory?

Comment: Yes, all the other files are in the same directory. I also checked the permissions of the folder as well as the file, and they seem to be fine.

Comment: hmm that is strange @Sourish. Are all the file 'owners' the same when you look in the file properties (Details tab)? If you create a new excel sheet with the same data and point the SSIS to it do you get the same issue?